How to automate Filed test cases to create work items in Azure DevOps
I have the following requirements for a PowerShell script:
Objective: Automate the creation of Bug work items in Azure DevOps for each failed test case identified in the pipeline.
Current Setup:
Failed test case logs are collected during pipeline execution and stored as an artifact.
In the release pipeline, I have successfully assigned each failed test case to variables using a PowerShell script.
Expected Functionality:
The PowerShell script should:
Use Azure DevOps REST API to create a Bug work item for each failed test case.
Populate the System.Title and System.Description fields in the Bug work item with relevant information about the failed test case (e.g., test case name, failure details).
Environment Details:
Organization URL: <organization_url>
Project Name: <project_name>
Personal Access Token (PAT) with sufficient permissions.
Technical Details:
The script should use a REST API endpoint to create work items in Azure DevOps.
Include proper error handling and debug logs for troubleshooting.
Could you help me with a PowerShell script that meets these requirements?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
